# How to remove the shortcut Alt + right click from LXDE so it's available to applications?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, lxde

I work with Blender and use the shortcut Alt + right click a lot to select edge loops but Lubuntu uses it to resize a window. How can i remove it ?
If possible i would like a command line in the terminal that removes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to modify your `lubuntu-rc.xml` in `~/.config/openbox/`. There are two sections within the `<mouse>` tag that contain the following:

```
<mousebind button="A-Right" action="Press">
  <action name="Focus"/>
  <action name="Raise"/>
  <action name="Unshade"/>
</mousebind>


<mousebind button="A-Right" action="Drag">
  <action name="Resize"/>
</mousebind>
```

You can comment them out or remove them completely. Fire up a new terminal, type `sudo openbox --restart`, and that shortcut should no longer resize the window.

Comment: Thank you for helping me.
It doesn't resize the window anymore but i still can't use the shortcut in Blender. Alt + right click doesn't select the continuity of edges.

Comment: Hmm, [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60961/how-to-use-the-alt-right-click-in-edit-mode-in-linux) seems like a similar if not the same issue. It looks like the only way to change it is to edit the shortcuts. Double-check your keyboard shortcuts in Blender to be sure that it's the one you're using.

Comment: I know i am the author in your link, but i wanted a solution for LXDE. In Mint i can make the Alt + Right click works in Blender. If it's not possible i could stick with Mint and wait for the next release of Lubuntu, it should use LXQt and have another shortcut manager.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice that you authored the other question. I wonder if there is any other OS shortcut conflicting with Blender.

Comment: I have removed every shortcuts between <mouse> and </mouse> and it works. But i will try to find what shortcut we have to delete.

Comment: I have found the second command to remove or comment:

      <mousebind button="A-Right" action="Press">
        <action name="Focus"/>
        <action name="Raise"/>
        <action name="Unshade"/>
      </mousebind>